# Average of number of itens in distinct orders grouped by month

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to understand the average number of items each order had for several distinct orders in a range of months.
Example:

```
Order_id| N_Item | Created_at
order 1 | item A | may-2020
order 1 | item B | may-2020
order 1 | item C | may-2020
order 2 | item A | may-2020
order 2 | item B | may-2020
order 3 | item C | may-2020

order 4 | item A | June-2020
order 4 | item B | June-2020
order 5 | item A | June-2020
```

So the result I'm looking is by grouping the months, May for example would be: (3items+2items+1items)/3orders

```
may-2020  | 5.33
june-2020 | 1.5
```

I'm struggling with this SQL query. No idea where to begin...

```
from orders o join order_items i on o.id = i.order_id
where i.product_id not in ("wpp001", "147426")
and date(o.start_picking_at) between {{data_inicial}} and {{data_final}}
group by 1
```

This is the far I went, but not sure how to group by month nor average the values
Can you help me out?

Comment: looks like school work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arithmetic is off (1 + 2 + 3) / 3 = 2, not 5.33.

But you can use:

```
select created_at, count(*) / count(distinct order_id)
from t
group by created_at;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something with steps

```
select
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y%m')
  , count( distinct order_id) orders
  , count( n_item) items
  , count( distinct order_id) / count( n_item) as average_items_per_order
from order_items
group by 
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y%m')
```

FYI - in the last column, you will want to convert the intermediate items to decimal allowing format so that you do not lose precision.  I don't use MySQL, so I don't recall the syntax for casting.